# spl_autoload_register() and/or __autoload() are 'triple loading'

Tags: php, debugging

I'm logging my classnames in `spl_autoload_register()` to trace the app's flow. On each page refresh of my app I'm seeing the classes being loaded three times. Same thing happens if I use `__autoload()` which leads me to believe that there is a problem with the architecture and not the autoloading implementation. How should I go about debugging this? I don't know where to start.

Comment: Make a single request with code which does _never_ do related requests (images, css, etc.) unlike browsers, `wget` for instance. If there's no duplication there, something else is loaded which routes through your code, which is most often the case. Other debugging tools you might want to look at: `get_included_files()`, `debug_print_backtrace()`, and not unimportant, _show use the code with which you log this, because there might be an error in there_.

Comment: @Wrikken Brilliant. `wget` works as expected - no triplicates. I will look into using the other two functions you mentioned to track this down further. Thank you, my friend!

Answer (score 0):

I had two missing image resources and some inaccurate .htaccess directives. Apache was trying to serve the images as 404 pages - thereby causing my app to boot up each time. Fixed it with this:

```
...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|jpeg|png|css|js|svg)$
...
```